# AngularJS $state.go with full page refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Seems like $state.go('statename') works like a back button in the browser. A cached Type.

I need to refresh the page when state changes like clicking the refresh button in the browser.

I need to reload/refresh the full page when the state changes, basically re-initializing the controller.

Tried with $state.go('statename', {}, {reload: true}), but with no effect.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please be more precise about what you're expecting to happen, and what happens instead? `reload` will reload the controller, but won't restart the whole app. But of course, if you have in-memory state in the app, that won't be reset. It's probably a design problem, but it's hard to advice without a clear problem, and without any code.

Comment: What's happening--$state.go('statename') taking me to 'statename' state but doesnot reinitialize the controller, as a result the view associated with 'statename' doesnot refresh.... What I am expecting --- $state.go('statename') should reinitialize the controller and the view associated with it should refresh the page full. Basically what happens when we use PHP, .Net etc to navigate between pages(browser reloads)

Comment: It will create a new instance of the controller associated to that state if you specify `{reload: true}`.

Comment: I have used that..but with no effect

Comment: It does have an effect. I've used that successfully a whole lot of time. Post a complete minimal example, in a plunkr, reproducing the problem. Or at least, elaborate on your actual problem, and post your code.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for your time and valuable suggestions and comments. I will post that soon, as I need to deliver the module by tomorrow, so a bit short on time. Meanwhile samitier's suggestion is apparently working, though I think its not that elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind injecting `$window`, you can try with `$window.location.reload()`